# Group values in one column, flatten grouped values and create new columns

Tags: excel, csv

Perhaps I am asking too much from Excel (Mac OSX) here.
Sorry that the title may be vague, it's easily explained via examples:
We have a table like

```
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| username | course  |  group  |   role   |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| A        | music   | X       | student |
| A        | math    | Y       | student  |
| A        | spanish | Z       | student  |
| B        | music   | X       | student  |
| B        | math    | Y       | teacher  |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
```

I want to group by username but kind of 'flatten' the groupings, to create a table that looks like this:

```
+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
| username | course1 |  group1  |  role1  | course2 | group2 |  role2  | course3 | group3 |  role3  |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
| A        | music   | X        | student | math    | Y      | student | spanish | Z      | student |
| B        | music   | X        | student | math    | Y      | teacher |         |        |         |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Whatever I do in Excel would have to be able to dynamically name and create these columns - i.e. some users will have up to 'course3' others up to 'course12'

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This could be done but doing it would require a lot of support infrastructure, and I don't think this is a good presentation. I'd recommend a different layout. Why is it you want your data displayed like this?

Comment: We need a csv file in the desired format to upload to a system that wants it in that format. But knowing that it is very 'non-trivial' is useful - means I'm not missing something easy

Comment: Advanced usage of pivot tables might get something like this, but if I were tasked with this, I'd just do the work in code, and leave excel out of it. Excel is not the best tool for the job, IMO.